# WordPress url error on IIS 7

Tags: wordpress, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have install WordPress as a web application at **IIS 7** but I have a problem.

When I access the site like `http://foo.com/wordpress/` it works great.
But when I go to `http://foo.com/WordPress/` it give me **404 error**. `http://foo.com/WordPress/index.php` works, but don't give any posts from the database.

So can I do anything that will redirect `/WordPress/` or `/WORDPRESS/` to `/wordpress/`?

Comment: I think the problem is that the wordpress application don't find any default file to show when you write /WordPRess/

Comment: Set "index.php" as a default page to fix that 2nd part.  The 1st problem is weird to me though, Apache's always been the case sensitive one.

Comment: Well i did change the 404 template to the right url, wordpress have a own 404 error function build in so you don't have to use iis 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Its bit older question, but I was dealing with the same issue and haven't found any clear answer, so this might actually help somebody. I fixed the same with following steps:

1) Make sure that the  rules in the web.config of the folder with wordpress are case insensitive. My web.config looks like this:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

2)Install and activate WordPress plugin (the first code snippet) from this link: [case insensitive permalinks](http://www.unfocus.com/2007/08/31/case-insensitive-permalinks-plugin-for-wordpress/)

It isn't the best solution, because it doesn't make the nice canonical url's with 301 permanent redirect for example, but works as a quick fix.